# AWS EKS Cluster Autoscaler - Scale-In Policy

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, amazon-eks

I've a CA (Cluster Autoscaler) deployed on EKS followed [this post](https://eksworkshop.com/scaling/deploy_ca/). What I'm wondering is CA automatically scales down the cluster whenever at least **a single pod** is deployed on that node i.e. if there are 3 nodes with the capacity of 8 pods, if 9th pod comes up, CA would provision 4th nodes to run that 9th pod. What I see is CA is continuously terminating & creating a node randomly chosen from within the cluster disturbing other pods & nodes.

How can I tell EKS (without defining minimal nodes or disabling scale-in policy in ASG) to **not to kill the node having at least 1 pod running on it**. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use pod as unit. CA work with resources cpu and memory unit.

If the cluster does not have enough cpu or memory it add one new.

You have to play with your requests resources (in the pod definition) or redefine your node to take an instance type with more or less resources depending how many pod you want on each.

Or you can play with the param `scale-down-utilization-threshold`

https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-are-the-parameters-to-ca

Comment: Each pod has `memory: 1500Mi` resource limits. How does it related to `scale-down-utilization-threshold`?

Comment: You mean if Memory + CPU utilisation of a pod on a node is less than 50% of the node, CA would consider it for removal & this is configurable via `scale-down-utilization-threshold` flag?

Comment: It is not resources limits but resource requests.  If you don't have request CA will think than it can start you pod on a node with 10mo do memory and kill the new node.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Actually I was experimenting. I also defined resources requests to be the same as resources limits. It seems CA is still deleting a random node from the EKS.

PS: I'm using helm for deploying stuff on EKS.

Comment: I think I have to set `scale-down-utilization-threshold`. I can't get how to calculate this value in terms of CPU & Memory defined in the deployment.